# how to find available wireless networks

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, network-manager

I'm using an HP Pavilion dv6000 I've looked at other answers similar to this question how ever when I look at my network symbol it doesn't say anything that the answer below says

"Make sure that your wifi hardware switch is on or not. It is either F2 or F12 or near to it. Once the switch is enabled, there is a small fan-like applet on the top panel (Gnome Network Manager), fourth from the right.

Click on it and if there is no tick mark on the option 'Enable Wireless', enable it. Wait till your wifi connection name appears."

it how says 'Enable Networking' my wi-fi switch is on and I've tried using terminal to kill the applet as another answer suggests trying. Does anyone have any other ideas that might help?

Just in case anybodies curious as to how I'm posting this I'm on my other ubuntu laptop that's running an older version.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0280]'`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter the following comand

```
sudo iwlist scan
```

This will list all the Wifi signals you PC can see as shown below.

```
warren@dell:~$ sudo iwlist scan
[sudo] password for warren: 
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 4C:60:DE:6B:85:4A
                    Channel:36
                    Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
                    Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"HS-1gid46vaylveagu59b3ks232h"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000057e902c95aa
                    Extra: Last beacon: 3580ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 001C48532D3167696434367661796C7665616775353962336B7332333268
                    IE: Unknown: 01088C129824B048606C
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A6E081BFFFF000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D16240D0400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD730050F204104A00011010440001021041000100103B00010310470010C8F7D19B3C39E65DD5B3EC2A8601640D102100074E6574676561721023000844474E44333330301024000631323334353610420004313233341054000800060050F20400011011000844474E4433333030100800020088
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180201F0050000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C336E081BFFFF000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C34240D0400000000000000000000000000000000000000
          Cell 02 - Address: 1C:AF:F7:63:A5:26
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TALKTALK-63A526"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000014c7e111bc
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4444ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000F54414C4B54414C4B2D363341353236
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
```